# Any way to get a PageReference.setRedirect(true) to return a 302 status and location rather than some JavaScript that submits a form?

Tags: visualforce, pagereference

I am attempting to invoke a short sequence of Visualforce pages from an external system (i.e. server-side) rather than a browser.

A GET of one of the Visualforce pages does a client-side redirect via [setRedirect(true)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_setRedirect.htm) on a PageReference. But the mechanism for this appears to be JavaScript emitted in the returned page that does a form submit to the new URL. That is fine if executing in a browser that has the HTML parsing and JavaScript etc. But it would be much easier for my external system if the redirect was done via a [302 status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) and a new location header.

I suspect that this behaviour is hard-wired in Visualforce as the assumed consumer is a browser. But thought I'd check here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer is no. Please answer if you discover otherwise.